# Запятая перед вводным словом

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

"Однако потом людей стало больше, а значит, все пошло быстро, в спешке". После союза "а" будет стоять запятая или нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Однако потом людей стало больше, а значит, все пошло быстро, в спешке.**

**Союз А относится к вводному слову ЗНАЧИТ** и обособляется вместе с ним. Вводное слово **нельзя убрать из предложения**, оставив союз А, поэтому союз А не относится к структуре предложения.

**Грамматический анализ**

Это предложение относится к ССП, союзное соединение (союз А + вводное слово ЗНАЧИТ) обозначает сопоставительно-следственные отношения между предикативными частями сложного предложения.

Союз ОДНАКО ― присоединительный.